# Get a value from a list in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2010 and get values from a list using the code below.

It might be called like this: `getValueFromList("addresses", "secondName", "city", "manhattan");`

It will return the "secondName" of the first entry that has "city = manhattan". Is there a way to make it more efficient?

```
private string getValueFromList(string theList, string returnColumnName,   string matchColumnName, string valueToMatch)
{
    try
    {
        SPSite siteh2 = SPContext.Current.Site;

        using (SPWeb oWeb = siteh2.OpenWeb())
        {

            //SPWeb oWeb = SPControl.GetContextSite(Context).OpenWeb();
            SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[theList];

            SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
            oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + matchColumnName + "' />" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>" + valueToMatch + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            //oQuery.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Username' /><Value Type='Text'>whelanp</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

            SPListItemCollection results = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

            if (results.Count == 0)
                return "";

            foreach (SPListItem oListItem in results)
            {
                return cleanValue(oListItem[returnColumnName].ToString());
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI if you haven't seen it: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As this is a review of code, wheter it is for SP or not, I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

### Naming conventions:

As per the Microsoft guidelines, use **P**ascal**C**ase for method names. Read more here: [**Capitalization Conventions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx). Your method names will become `GetValueFromList` and `CleanValue`.

### Object Initialization and Format String:

Use the [**String.Format**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method to build your string, don't use concatenation. The building of your CAML query will be:

```
var spQuery = new SPQuery
{
    Query = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>", matchColumnName , valueToMatch)
};
```

More reading on [**Object and Collection Initializers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

### Get SharePoint list:

Don't blindly use `web.Lists["listName"]`, it depends on the number of lists you have in your environment what call you should use.

Using `web.Lists["listName"]`, SharePoint will look for all lists in the current web-object and fetch all metadata from them. Then it compares the name you provided and return the correct list.

And `SPWeb.GetList("url/to/list")` will make a call to the DB for each list for which info is needed.

If you have a lot of lists (thousands), use the second method, otherwise the first will normally score better. Also, this depends on the performance of your hardware. But in general, I tend to avoid the indexer (using the second method or even `web.TryGetList("listTitle")`).

### The foreach loop:

You have this piece of code:

```
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in results)
{
    return cleanValue(oListItem[returnColumnName].ToString());
}
```

Why have a loop if you will return on the first item? If you only want to return the first entry, use the [**SPQuery.RowLimit**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.rowlimit.aspx) property and set it to 1:

```
var spQuery = new SPQuery
{
    Query = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>", matchColumnName , valueToMatch),
    RowLimit = 1
};
```

Following code:

```
SPListItemCollection results = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

if (results.Count == 0)
    return "";

foreach (SPListItem oListItem in results)
{
    return cleanValue(oListItem[returnColumnName].ToString());
}
return "";
```

will now look like this:

```
var results = list.GetItems(spQuery);
if (results.Count == 0)
    return "";

var item = results[0];
return CleanValue(item[returnColumnName].ToString());
```

Or in one `return` statement:

```
return results.Count > 0 ? CleanValue(item[returnColumnName].ToString()) : String.Empty;
```

### Nitpicking:

- Variable names:

  - `theList` should be replaced by `listName` or `listTitle`.
  - Avoid adding the `o` before the names, use `spList` and `spQuery` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Method names in .net should be `PascalCase`, so that would be `GetValueFromList` (and `CleanValue`), consistent with the rest of the framework and with what .net devs expect to see; Hungarian-style prefixes like the `o` of `oWeb` and `oList` are annoying too - nobody cares that an object is an `Object`. Name things after *what they're used for*, not for their type.

It's not clear what `theList` is supposed to be. From the parameter name I'd deem it a `List<string>` perhaps, and then `source` would have been a better name - but then this becomes surprising:

> ```
> SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[theList];
> ```

Assuming the `SPListCollection` indexer uses a list's `Title` property, it seems `title` would be a more accurate parameter name to use.

This is repeated 3 times:

> ```
> return "";
> ```

Should be `string.Empty` to better convey the intent. But let's look closer at the return mechanism:

> ```
> if (results.Count == 0)
>     return "";
>
> foreach (SPListItem oListItem in results)
> {
>     return cleanValue(oListItem[returnColumnName].ToString());
> }
> return "";
> ```

The `foreach` loop isn't going to even iterate once if `results` is empty: that `if(results.Count == 0)` check is redundant, the `return "";` after the loop is already covering for the "no results" case.

The `catch(Exception ex)` block is a problem though. You're not using `ex`, so you might as well have `catch(Exception)` there - but the real problem is that you're effectively thwarting what exceptions are for.

If I give that method `string.Empty`, or a `null` value for `theList`, or a column name that doesn't exist - I *expect* an exception to be thrown. Exceptions are good, exceptions are your friends: exceptions help you diagnose and remove bugs in the rest of your code - by swallowing all exceptions here, you make it harder to diagnose problems that might exist at a much higher level, e.g. your UI has a bad binding and consistently ends up calling `GetValueFromList` with a `null` parameter, but you have no way of telling if the `""` return value is because there really isn't any such matching value, column or list, or because an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` was swallowed there.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [@Abbas](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140129/59161) last snippet:

> ```
> var results = oList.GetItems(spQuery);
> if (results.Count == 0)
>     return "";
>
> var item = results[0];
> return CleanValue(item[returnColumnName].ToString());
> ```

If you are using C# 6 you can turn `CleanValue` into an extension and make it really nice looking:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static string Clean(this object obj) 
    {
        ...obj.ToString and clean-up 
    }
}
```

then you could just to this:

```
return oList.GetItems(spQuery).SingleOrDefault()?.Clean() ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: SharePoint 2010 relies on .NET 3.5 (SP1) and does not support .NET 4 or higher, so this will not work.